# last object serialized gets overwritten

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

I am writing a program for keeping track of library books. There is an object book that includes a title, sku number, price and quantity. All the books are stored in an Array List. I'm trying to serialize the books and add new books but every time a book is added the last is overwritten.

here is the code below to load objects from save

```
public static void readSave() {
        
        File stockFile = new File("inventory.txt");
        
        try {
            if(!stockFile.createNewFile() && stockFile.length() != 0) {
                ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(stockFile));
                int size = objIn.readInt();
                
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    Book t = (Book) objIn.readObject();
                    bookList.add(t);
                }
                
                objIn.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

here is my save method and it is set to save every time the program executes.

```
public static void save() {
        File inventoryFile = new File("inventory.txt");
        
        ObjectOutputStream objOut;
        try {
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(inventoryFile));
        
            objOut.writeInt(bookList.size());
            Iterator<Book> i = bookList.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                objOut.writeObject(i.next());
            }
        
            objOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

below is my main method which calls these functions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    readSave();
                    CampusBookWindow window = new CampusBookWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                save();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the load code to explain the issue more clearly - for example are you loading the file, appending items then call save or just calling save() with a new list which then wipes all previously saved books in inventory.txt?

Comment: Nothing in your posted code jumps out at me as wrong.  Is it possible your `CampusBookWindow` is just modifying the last entry, instead of adding an entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was when I hit the add book button I would not create a new book object for that item, but instead I was reassigning that last book object so the object last book object was erased from the bookList array list